# ZF2.3 translate validation message

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am trying to translate the validation messages to another language. I am using ZF 2.3 and the skeleton application.

I've configured the translator:

```
'translator' => array(
    'locale' => 'nl_NL',
    'translation_file_patterns' => array(
        array(
            'type'     => 'gettext',
            'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
            'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
        ),
        array(
            'type'     => 'phpArray',
            'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../data/language',
            'pattern'  => '%s.php',
        ),
    ),
),
```

But the following string is not translated in my view file (and im sure this string is included in my language file):

```
echo $this->translate('Invalid type given. String, integer or float expected');
```

And also the messages from the validators are still default / not translated.

Ive searched for solutions everywhere, but it seems like translations have been refactored in ZF 2.3, and all solutions I can find are for older versions.

The following documentation page should offer a solution:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.validator.messages.html

But the code under 'Using pre-translated validation messages' is not working:

```
$translator = new Zend\Mvc\I18n\Translator();
$translator->addTranslationFile(
    'phpArray',
    'resources/languages/en.php',
    'default',
    'en_US'
);

Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator::setDefaultTranslator($translator);
```

This will result in a fatal error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Zend\Mvc\I18n\Translator::__construct() must implement interface Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorInterface, none given
```

Is there a known solution for ZF 2.3 ?

**Solution:**

In config:

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array (
        'translator' => 'Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorServiceFactory',
    ),
),
```

In Module bootstrap event:

```
    $translator = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('translator');
    $translator->addTranslationFile('phpArray', __DIR__ . '/language_php/Zend_Validate.php', 'default', 'nl_NL');

    \Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator::setDefaultTranslator(new \Zend\Mvc\I18n\Translator($translator));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is stated in 
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.validator.html#translating-messages
where they say: *A new service has also been registered with the MVC, MvcTranslator*

So you can initialize the $translator variable with

```
$translator = $serviceLocator->get('MvcTranslator');
```

You have to ensure to have access to the serviceLocator.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Matthias.  

I've tried your solution, but i'm not sure how to use it.  

First attempt:  


    `$MvcTranslator = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('MvcTranslator');  

    $translator = new \Zend\Mvc\I18n\Translator($MvcTranslator);  

    $translator->addTranslationFile(  
      'phpArray',  
      'resources/languages/en.php',  
      'default',  
      'en_US'  
    );  

    \Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator::setDefaultTranslator($translator);`

But this results in:  

    `Unable to call method "addTranslationFile"; does not exist in translator'`

Comment: Also adding translation file directly to the MvcTranslator won't work, as this service does not know the method AddTranslationFile neither.

Comment: I used `$translator = $serviceLocator->get('MvcTranslator'); $translator->addTranslationFile('phpArray', 'module/Application/language/de/Zend_Validate.php', 'default', 'de_DE'); AbstractValidator::setDefaultTranslator($translator);` in an AbstractFactory and it works fine.

Comment: Output of $serviceLocator->get('MvcTranslator');

`object(Zend\Mvc\I18n\Translator)#246 (1) { ["translator":protected]=> object(Zend\Mvc\I18n\DummyTranslator)#247 (0) { } } `

But on this object its not possible to use addTranslationFile:

` 'Unable to call method "addTranslationFile"; does not exist in translator'`

How did you configure your MvcTranslator?

Comment: I have the following lines in the module.config.php return array: `    'service_manager' => array('factories' => array( 'translator' => 'Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorServiceFactory',),), ` . I don't know if this is the necessary step. It worked with my configuration

Comment: Thanks for your help Matthias. I fixed it by using your factory config, and configuring translator on bootstrap. Probably not the right way, but it works!

Answer (score 3):

This is my working code for translate validation messages:

**config/autoload/global.php**

```
<?php
return array(

        .........

    'service_manager' => array(
        'aliases' => array(
            'translator' => 'MvcTranslator',
        ),
    ),

        .........

);
```

**module/Application/Module.php**

```
<?php

namespace Application;

use Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');

        $serviceManager = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
        $translator = $serviceManager->get('translator');

        //$locale = $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'];
        $locale = 'es_ES';
        //$locale = 'en_US';

        $translator->setLocale(\Locale::acceptFromHttp($locale));
        $translator->addTranslationFile(
            'phpArray',
            'lang/es/Zend_Validate.php',
            'default',
            'es_ES'
        );
        AbstractValidator::setDefaultTranslator($translator);
    }
}
```

I hope this can help you. Have a nice day.

Comment: BTW "lang/es/Zend_Validate.php" is not a valid path in your case.

Comment: it works with this absolute path from project root: `'./vendor/zendframework/zendframework/resources/languages/es/Zend_Validate.php'`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php
      $translatorI = new \Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator();
      $translatorI->setLocale('es');


      $translator = new \Zend\Mvc\I18n\Translator($translatorI);
      $translator->addTranslationFile(
          'phpArray',
          './vendor/zendframework/zendframework/resources/languages/es/Zend_Validate.php',
          'default',
          'es'
      );

      \Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator::setDefaultTranslator($translator);
?>
```

Comment: \Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator::setDefaultTranslator($translator);
did the trick for me